# How can I find the PID for software where the name of the software is different from the executable?

Tags: linux, kill, ps, pid

I run "Videos" software from the Dash in Ubuntu. After some minutes the software freezes.

I've tried searching for the PID of the software to kill it, but I can't find any result with these commands:

```
pgrep Videos
ps -eo cmd,pid,stime
```

I don't know the stime of the process.

I have to restart my computer and after login, I see the software is executed by `totem` command.

How can I find the PID for software where the name of the software is different from that of the executable file?

Comment: Process name of Videos in Ubuntu is 'totem'.

Comment: The executable *is* totem, "Videos" is *not* the name of the executable but the "Application name" according to XDG Desktop Spec

Comment: Right,  But when you click on Videos Icon, how can you find pid of this process? (because there are some applications that executable file name is not same of the application).